# How to make 'path' as empty in @RestResource to have endpoint only as /search{?name}

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a custom method in the repository for which I would like to change the endpoint produced by Spring. Need to ignore the "path" that is coming after "/search"

Currently below is the endpoint that is getting exposed (`/search/findByName{?name}`).

```
 "customFind": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/productType/search/findByName{?name}",
            "templated": true
        }
```

Current Code:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "productType", path = "productType")
public interface ProductTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductType, Long> {

    @RestResource(path ="findByName", rel = "customFind")
    ProductType findByNameIgnoreCase(@Param("name") String productTypeName);

}
```

Need to change the "path" so that I wanted to access my endpoint like below.

```
 "customFind": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/productType/search{?name}",
            "templated": true
        }
```

I have tried specifying `path=""`, but nothing worked.

I expect the final endpoint to be like 
`http://localhost:8080/productType/search?name="wooden"`

Answer (score 0):

As per the Spring Data REST [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/).

```
All query method resources are exposed under the search resource.
```

So if you want a custom behavior you need to write your own custom controller method.